# Import JSON object from an URL without using libraries

Tags: javascript, json

How can I import a JSON object from a website without using libraries like JQuery? I'd like to access some data using pure JavaScript.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `fetch`, check this out! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch("some url that returns json")
  .then(res => {
    res.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    do something with the data
  })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.